# how could I fit this object into this hole perfectly?

Tags: modeling, snapping

Was messing around with an object i was working on and had moved the object highlighted in the picture out of its space by accident, I then saved and quit by accident and now have no idea how to place it back in perfectly. I do not have any autosaves from before this big mistake. [image]

Comment: Hi :). I suppose vertex snapping could get you there. Do you remember how it looked before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a technique that will work if you have moved the object but not rotated it:

[image: example of plug and hole]

Your object appears to be made of stacked cubes.  I've made one consisting of two cubes.  Let's assume you want one of the cubes, probably the larger one to fit in the hole so that the top face is flush:

1. Set an origin for the object that helps position it.

   - In Edit mode, select the four faces that make up the sides of the cube.
   - Move the cursor to the selection
   - Go to Object Mode and set the object's origin to the 3D cursor. (shortcut Right Click and select *Set Origin* → *Origin to 3D Cursor*)
     [image: Resulting cursor placement]
2. Place the 3D cursor in the hole to help position the object

   - Select the four inside edges of the hole in the object that match the four outside edges.
   - Move the cursor to the selection
     [image: cursor positioned in selection]
3. Move the object using the snapping menu
   [image: correctly positioned object]

The key to these steps is moving the 3D cursor to the selection and vice versa.  This is done by typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>S</kbd> to bring up this pie menu and the <kbd>8</kbd> to select *Cursor to Selected* or <kbd>2</kbd> to select *Selected to Cursor*

[image: Cursor snapping menu]

If you can't get an exact match, and the object does not have rotation applied, you can also use the local coordinates when moving.  (Shortcut <kbd>G</kbd> followed by repeating the axis you want to move twice, ie <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to move on the local axis.)  You can accomplish similar by changing the Transformation Orientation:

[image: Transformation Orientation]

And, of course, in the final analysis you can use Vertex snapping as suggested by Jachym Michal in a comment on your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sorry i marked it so late though haha

Comment: @Jameson4279 you're welcome.  I'm glad it worked for you.  No worries about being late.